# Degassing silicone solution with negative pressure

Tags: chemical-engineering

I am planning to use [polydimethylsiloxane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane) (PDMS) to create a phantom for mimicking tissue for imaging. For this, I plan on using [SYLGARD® 184](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/761036?lang=en&region=US), which is a viscous liquid. When adding other components to it, air bubbles will be introduced.

I have learned that one way (available to me) to remove bubbles / de-gas the solution is by using a vacuum pump to create negative pressure. What negative pressure is sufficient to remove the air from the gel-like solution?

Comment: The answer will also depend on the amount of time the negative pressure is applied.

Comment: @ChrisMueller I would want to limit it to less than one hour. Any practical suggestions?

Comment: Use an old vacuum and find out. If the negative pressure is too strong, introduce a leak into the system; if it's too weak you need a bigger vacuum or you have a leak.

Just remember that vacuums use the airflow through them to cool themselves and you will be putting a lot of load on the pump to maintain a negative pressure, so make sure you don't fry it by running it for too long consecutively.

Comment: @thepowerofnone [Here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002VBW9R8/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER) I found a good size vacuum desiccator, so I hope after getting some negative pressure, I can just close the valve and let it stay. It should hold the vacuum up to 24 hours. At this point I just need to select a reasonably strong pump, so I would like to know what minimum negative pressure it should create.

Comment: Practical tip.  As the the dissolved gas leaves the resin, it may cause the resin to foam-up and overflow the bucket.  Use a bucket that's 2x the volume of your batch.  It may also help to outgas gradually.

Comment: U$190 for 10g, too bad you couldn't find something less expensive ...

Answer (score 1):

15-30 mins under any vacuum pump will be fine. If there are any air bubbles still there at the surface I recommend to burst it with pressurized air gun.
Make sure that your vacuum chamber lid is sealed well. Some time it is useful to use vacuum grease to achieve that.